# Advantages to using a DNS service for a server?

Tags: domain-name-system

Are there any advantages/disadvantages to using an external DNS service like DynDNS or Zerigo DNS when operating a server (specifically, a VPS from Linode?)

Obviously I can use the DNS offered by Linode (my host), or Gandi.net (my registrar); are there any reasons (not) to use an external DNS service?

Answer (score 0):

Advantages are ease of setup and no need for a DynDNS account. Disadvantages are if you're site or application has been running for a long time and you need DNS to propagate through DynDNS. It could take up to a few days for DNS to update across the net. I generally plan for 48-72 hours for DNS to populate through another DNS server. Hope this helps!

Comment: DNS records are cached, not propagated. The TTL of the DNS record determines how long that record may be cached.